# can AWS elastic beanstalk be configured or moved to another AZ

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I recently deployed a ruby on rails app on elastic beanstalk.

```
 eb init 
 eb create nameofthebeanstalkapp
 eb deploy
```

Basically this will initialize the region and some other settings but not the AZ location.

For example, I selected North Virgin, but it didnt ask the AZ location. So it creates it in us-east-1c.
I would prefer it to be in us-east-1b where my RDS service is located.

How do I change over my EC2 instance to us-east-1b from us-east-1c ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do that using [Elastic Beanstalk Web Console](https://console.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/home):

If your instance in **Classic environment**:

1. Open your application and then your environment.
2. Click **Configuration** in the left sidebar menu.
3. Click **Scaling** box title.
4. Set your EC2 instance AZ there.

If your instance in **VPC environment**:

1. Open your application and then your environment.
2. Click **Configuration** in the left sidebar menu.
3. Click **VPC** box title.
4. Set your EC2 instance AZ there.

Of course, you can do that using CLI by doing the same thing (change the scaling/VPC options).